# Is it possible to keep in memory a PointerProperty different from bpy.props?

Tags: python, properties

I would like to store some properties in the scene, and on other bpy.data objects, I would like to create lists and dictionaries, but I am noticing that when the project is restarted, even if saved, these properties disappear. Example:

```
class SceneProp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    test_dict_prop = {}
    test_list_prop = []
    classic_bpy_props: bpy.props.StringProperty() #etc
    
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.scene_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SceneProp)
```

I assumed that the properties of type not bpy.props were stored, but this is not the case, when blender is restarted, the dictionaries or the list will be empty. I foolishly thought it might work like that, but it isn't.

In addition, as far as a list is concerned, it could be solved with an EnumProperty, but it is not much for the purpose, as it will only be able to store strings, while I would also need to store Blender data objects.

Is there a practical solution? Always keeping pointed to a Blender property?

Comment: Short answer I think is no for PropertyGroups. You can use a CollectionProperty to store a List. For a dictionary I don't think you can at least not with some boilerplate, but you can directly assign custom properties as List or Dictionary though : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87871/86891 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53393/how-can-i-store-lists-dictionaries-in-an-object

Comment: Wow, this is science fiction to me, really useful, it works great, I didn't know about this possibility.